# php strtotime() produce different result in window mac linux?

Tags: php, date, time

```
$today   = date("Y-m-d H:i");
$endtime = date("2011-09-14 00:00");
$second  = abs(time() - strtotime($endtime, strtotime($today, 0)));

echo $second;
```

I want to find the second from future date - today date, but the result is different in all platform where:

- mac: 21343,
- ubuntu: 68172 and
- window: 50175.

After convert the second to hour:minute:second, the different is around 10-15 hours. Anyone know other method that work similar to `strtotime`?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe because the systems have different timezones or system clocks

Comment: Then is there any way to set timezones or system clocks in php?

Comment: @biokeev `date_default_timezone_set`

Answer (score 3):

You're making it quite complicated. `date("2011-09-14 00:00")` is nonsense, just `"2011-09-14 00:00"` will do the same thing. `strtotime($today, 0)` seems weird too. Only this should do just fine:

```
$second = abs(time() - strtotime('2011-09-14 00:00:00'));
```

Make sure you set the timezones to be the same on all systems using `date_default_timezone_set`, which is probably were your actual problem comes from.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably getting the time settings from your server (which has variable time), you can set a timezone on all scripts for it to give you the same values.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');; //I usually put it at the top of the script
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 2):

Your code is over complicated and has some weirdness in it, but this has already been pointed out in @deceze's answer, so I won't go over that again.

Others have also suggested possible reasons for the actual discrepancies you're seeing, so I won't go into that either.

What I will say is that I would always avoid using the `strtotime()` function where possible, because it is very slow and has the some potential for thowing unexpected results when the date is in an ambiguous format (ie `dd-mm-yyyy` vs `mm/dd/yyyy`). Even in cases like yours where the input is not ambiguous, it is still a very slow piece of code for what it does because it has to parse the date string without knowing what format to expect.

Recent versions of PHP provide a much better alternative if you're doing date arithmetic. Check out the [`date_diff()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php), as well as other functions from the [DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). This class provides *much* better functionality for handling dates than the old-style PHP techniques you're using.

Note that to get the best from the DateTime class, you're going to need to be running the latest version of PHP - ie PHP 5.3. But since PHP 5.2 is no longer supported, you really ought to make sure you're on 5.3 now anyway.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank for additional info, well because i need to submit this project to my lecture and the php version might be less than 5.3 so i can't use it.

Comment: @bitokeev - you can still use the date class in 5.2; just not all of it - eg I think `datediff()` was added in 5.3. But even the 5.2 version is better than what you're doing now.